# TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable while using ->

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, python-3.7

Writing a simple class which has a method that retuns[0,0]

```
    class Solution:
        def contain(self, nums: list[int], target: int) -> list[int]:
            return [0,0]


    Solution().contain(nums=[1,2,3,4], target=3)



    Traceback (most recent call last):
      line 1, in <module>
        class Solution:
      line 2, in Solution
        def contain(self, nums: list[int], target: int) -> list[int]:
    TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

if list[int], int are just placeholders why does the code run when I remove them (with def contain(self, nums, target):)?

Comment: You should use [`typing.List`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List) (Generic version of `list`), not `list`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because `list` needs to be `List`. Look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#type-aliases). Your code indexes the type `list`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifiaction and link.